# $(\textbf{r}\times\nabla)^{2}$ in spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

In polar coordinates,
$$\nabla = \partial_{r} \hat{\textbf{r}} +\frac{1}{r} \partial_{\theta} \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} +\frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)} \partial_{\phi} \hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}$$
such that $\textbf{r} = r \hat{\textbf{r}}$. Therefore,
$$\textbf{r} \times \nabla = \partial_{\theta} \hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}} -\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)} \partial_{\phi} \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}.$$
When I try to evaluate $(\textbf{r} \times \nabla) \cdot (\textbf{r} \times \nabla)$, I treat it as a column vector in the polar basis to obtain
$$(\textbf{r} \times \nabla) \cdot (\textbf{r} \times \nabla) = \partial^{2}_{\theta} +\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(\theta)} \partial^{2}_{\phi}.$$
However, I know this isn’t correct, and that I should get
$$(\textbf{r} \times \nabla) \cdot (\textbf{r} \times \nabla) = \partial^{2}_{\theta} +\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)} \partial_{\theta} +\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(\theta)} \partial^{2}_{\phi}.$$ But I can’t see where my approach is going wrong. I think it has something to do with the fact that, in cartesian coordinates, the spherical basis vectors are given by
$$    \hat{\textbf{r}} = \begin{pmatrix}
\sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) \\
\sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) \\
\cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) \cos(\phi) \\
\cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) \\
-\sin(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}} = \begin{pmatrix}
-\sin(\phi) \\
\cos(\phi) \\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
such that $\partial_{\phi} \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} = \cos(\theta) \hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}$ but still can’t get the correct result. So, my question is, why is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\renewcommand\vec\mathbf
\newcommand\vecg\boldsymbol
$

Consider the expression
$$
  (\vec r\times\nabla)\cdot(\vec r\times\nabla)f
$$
for some function $f$. The intent of such an expression is usually to compute $g = (\vec r\times\nabla)f$, then compute $h = (\vec r\times\nabla)\cdot g$. But $g$ contains coordinate dependence *that does not come from $f$*, and instead comes from $\vec r$ as well as the coordinate expression for $\nabla$. What you did is equivalent to ignoring all that extra coordinate dependence and only differentiating the coordinate dependence of $f$. What we should write is
$$\begin{aligned}
  &(\vec r\times\nabla)\cdot(\vec r\times\nabla)f
\\
    &\quad= \begin{aligned}[t] &\left(\hat{\vecg\phi}\dot\partial_\theta - \frac{\hat{\vecg\theta}}{\sin\theta}\dot\partial_\phi\right)\cdot\left(\dot{\hat{\vecg\phi}}\check\partial_\theta - \frac{\dot{\hat{\vecg\theta}}}{\sin\dot\theta}\check\partial_\phi\right)\check f
\\
      &+ \left(\hat{\vecg\phi}\dot\partial_\theta - \frac{\hat{\vecg\theta}}{\sin\theta}\dot\partial_\phi\right)\cdot\left(\hat{\vecg\phi}\check\partial_\theta - \frac{\hat{\vecg\theta}}{\sin\dot\theta}\check\partial_\phi\right)\dot{\check f}
\end{aligned}\end{aligned}$$
The dots $\dot\partial$ and checks $\check\partial$ specify exactly what the derivatives are diffentiating; the above expression stems from a kind of generalized product rule. The second term is the one you've already derived:
$$\begin{aligned}
  &\left(\hat{\vecg\phi}\dot\partial_\theta - \frac{\hat{\vecg\theta}}{\sin\theta}\dot\partial_\phi\right)\cdot\left(\hat{\vecg\phi}\check\partial_\theta - \frac{\hat{\vecg\theta}}{\sin\dot\theta}\check\partial_\phi\right)\dot{\check f}
\\
  &\quad = \partial_\theta^2f + \frac1{\sin^2\theta}\partial_\phi^2f
\end{aligned}$$
The first term expands to
$$
\hat{\vecg\phi}\cdot(\partial_\theta\hat{\vecg\phi})\partial_\theta f - \frac{\hat{\vecg\theta}}{\sin\theta}\cdot(\partial_\phi\hat{\vecg\phi})\partial_\theta f - \hat{\vecg\phi}\cdot\left[\partial_\theta\frac{\hat{\vecg\theta}}{\sin\theta}\right]\partial_\phi f + \frac{\hat{\vecg\theta}}{\sin\theta}\cdot\left[\partial_\phi\frac{\hat{\vecg\theta}}{\sin\theta}\right]\partial_\phi f.
$$
Exploiting facts about the orthogonality of derivatives of $\hat{\vecg\phi}$ and $\hat{\vecg\theta}$ leaves only the second term, which expands to
$$
  -\frac{\hat{\vecg\theta}}{\sin\theta}\cdot(\partial_\phi\hat{\vecg\phi})\partial_\theta f
    = \frac1{\tan\theta}\partial_\theta f
$$
as desired.

---

Rather than using the "generalized product rule" like I did above, you could also just compute $g = (\vec r\times\nabla)f$ and then $(\vec r\times\nabla)\cdot g$ in sequence.

---

One final note. There is another direction we could take. There is a vector identity
$$
  (a\times b)\cdot(c\times d) = (a\cdot c)(b\cdot d) - (b\cdot c)(a\cdot d).
$$
Properly keeping track of what we're differentiating, we can exploit this to get
$$\begin{aligned}
  &(\vec r\times\nabla)\cdot(\vec r\times\nabla)f
\\
    &\quad= (\vec r\times\dot\nabla)\cdot(\dot{\vec r}\times\check\nabla)\check f
      + (\vec r\times\dot\nabla)\cdot(\vec r\times\check\nabla)\dot{\check f}
\\
    &\quad=\begin{aligned}[t]
      &(\vec r\cdot\dot{\vec r})(\dot\nabla\cdot\check\nabla)\check f - (\dot\nabla\cdot\dot{\vec r})(\vec r\cdot\check\nabla)\check f
\\
      &+ (\vec r\cdot\vec r)(\dot\nabla\cdot\check\nabla)\dot{\check f} - (\dot\nabla\cdot\vec r)(\vec r\cdot\check\nabla)\dot{\check f}
    \end{aligned}
\\
  &\quad= \vec r\cdot\nabla f - 3\vec r\cdot\nabla f
     + r^2\nabla^2 f - (\vec r\cdot\dot\nabla)^2\dot f
\\
  &\quad= -2\vec r\cdot\nabla f
     + r^2\nabla^2 f - (\vec r\cdot\dot\nabla)^2\dot f.
\end{aligned}$$
In any coordinate system where $r$ is orthogonal to the other coordinates, we can write
$$
  (\vec r\times\nabla)^2f
    = r^2\nabla^2f - r^2\partial _r^2f - 2r\partial_rf.
$$
Expanding this expression using the well-known form of the Laplacian would also give the desired result.

Comment: thanks for your help